# How to calculate the integral $ \int_{-2}^{2} e^x\sqrt{4-x^2} \mathrm{d}\, x$?

Tags: definite-integrals

How to calculate the following integral:
$$
I=\int_{-2}^{2} e^x\sqrt{4-x^2} \,\mathrm{d} x = ?
$$

I try to use the substitution $x=2\sin\theta$ with $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and I get
$$
I=4\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{2\sin\theta} \cos^2\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta.
$$
Is there a explicit form of the integral with the form:
$$
\int e^{2\sin\theta} \cos^n\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta,\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: Please show your attempts. Users don't like this website being used as a homework machine.

Comment: This isn't something that can be found analytically; you have to resort to [numerical integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-2%7D%5E%7B2%7D+e%5Ex%5Csqrt%7B4-x%5E2%7D+dx).

Answer (score 3):

You properly wrote
$$I=4\int_{-\frac\pi 2}^{\frac\pi 2} e^{\sin(\theta)} \cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta$$ Now, let $t=\theta+\frac \pi 2$ to make
$$I=4 \int_0^\pi   e^{2 \cos (t)} \sin ^2(t)\,dt=2\int_0^\pi  e^{2 \cos (t)} \,dt-2\int_0^\pi  e^{2 \cos (t)} \cos(2t)\,dt $$ and now we face [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). This makes
$$I=2 \pi  I_0(2) -2 \pi  I_2(2)=2 \pi  I_1(2)$$